# Details related to Upstox margin calculation

Tags: margin, leverage

On the right is the screenshot of Upstox's span calculator for IDEA:
[Upstox's margin calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfGmX.png)

I just want to confirm if I am understanding this right or not? So, according to my understanding, it goes like this:

The price of IDEA is ₹46.2/share and if I want to buy 20 shares of IDEA at this price, the total amount is ₹46.2*20= ₹924. Now,in the screenshot, the total margin required is ₹84.18, hence they are providing a leverage of 924/84.18 = 10.97 times. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are required to put up 84.18 of the 924 then they are providing 839.82 in margin.

That means that you are putting up 9.11% of the purchase price and they are advancing you  90.89% of it.

So yes, the leverage would be 10.97 (924/84.18)